# Change default placeholder event duration

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar v2 in an agenda view, and need to be able to specify the duration of an event when the user selects a slot in the calendar. I've tried providing with a custom `selectHelper` function but  it gets constrained to a rectangle created by fullCalendar to match the size of the clicked slot; also I've tried specifying the `defaultTimedEventDuration` option, but it seems that the select event is not an actual *event*.

What I need: when the user clicks on a slot of the calendar, the event placeholder should have a specific duration based on the selected option of a field.

What I'm getting now: the event placeholder always has the same duration (a single slot).

My bet at the moment would be re-implementing the whole "placeholder select" interaction myself using the `dayClick` callback, but I was wondering if anyone else ever came up with this situation and how they dealt with it. I really don't like the idea of reinventing the wheel for such a subtle change.

Here's (the important bits of) what I have at the moment:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
  header: {
    left: 'prev',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay today next'
  },
  selectable: true,
  unselectAuto: false,
  selectHelper: true,
  slotDuration: '00:30:00'
});
```

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am looking at doing this now.

Comment: Can someone share the workaround solution to this?